# Get courts in complexes with minimal price

Tags: php, laravel

I have sport complexes and many corts in complexes .
 So I wanna select complexes by min price of court of it .

```
Complex1   court1 -price 2500
           court2  - price 3000
Complex2   court1 -price 5000
           court2 -price 1500
Result: Complex2(1500),Complex1(2500)
```

DB:

```
sport_complexes - 
    sc_id -compex id
    sc_city_id 
    sc_sport_type_id 
one to many 
courts-
    c_id 
    c_complex_id  -complex id
    c_coverage_id
    c_name
    c_cost  -price
```

I tried like this .

```
get all complexes to special sport type
$complexes = $sporttype->complexes;

ids of complexes        
$complexesIDs=$complexes->pluck('sc_id'); 

wanna order 
$array=\App\Models\Courts::whereIn('c_complex_id', $complexesIDs)->orderBy('c_cost')->get()->unique('c_complex_id ')
```

Comment: Please explain what is your issue.

Comment: @DorianTurba Im getting only 1 complex Complex2(1500)

Comment: `Please explain what is your issue.` in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty easy to solve, you may have this in your sporttype class (I even don't know if that is a class):

```
public function complexes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Complex');
}
```

You can create a new function to get the complexes ordered by cost:

```
public function complexesOrdered(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Complex')->orderBy('c_cost');
}
```

Another solution is traiting your relation as a function, so you can "requery" it:

```
$complexes = $sporttype->complexes()->orderBy('c_cost');
```

Cheers!

**EDIT:**

You have to make one more relationship to accomplish that:

***In your Complex class:***

```
public function courts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Court');
}
public function cheapCourt(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Court')->orderBy('c_cost');
}
```

***In your controller:***

```
complex->cheapCourt->first();
```

Comment: but complex doesnt have c_cost. It has many courts which have c_costs . So unfortunately your code doesn work

Comment: Check if my edit works! take in account that i don't know how your relations works. it may work similarly cheers!